# TS2585: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, es6-promise

I'm getting the following error

> node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.d.ts:82:59 - error TS2585: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.

Formatted it looks like this,

```
node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.d.ts:82:59 - error TS2585: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.                                                                   

82     toPromise<T>(this: Observable<T>, PromiseCtor: typeof Promise): Promise<T>;                                                                    
                                                             ~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

But the code I'm trying to run is right from the examples,

```
import { range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

range(1, 200).pipe(
  filter(x => x % 2 === 1),
  map(x => x + x)
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

I have in my `tsconfig.json`

```
"target": "ES2018",                                                                                       
"module": "es2015",   
"lib": ["es2015"],
```

I'm running Rx.js 6.3.3, TypeScript 3.2.2 under Node v11.6.0. I've tried

```
npm i --save-dev  @types/es6-promise
```

and just about every combination of changing `lib` and `module`

My ts config is exactly this,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "ES2016",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "es2015",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["es2016"],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your whole `tsconfig.json`? Can't reproduce the issue, it's working fine on my end. Maybe you should include or uninclude `node_modules`?

Comment: @NinoFiliu added full tsconfig.json

Comment: Reproduced this issue on my end. Program runs smoothly, but `tsc` is not happy with the compilation, I get the same errors as you: `TS2585: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`, `TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'`, and `TS2585: 'Symbol' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`. This looks like a bug to me, you should open an issue.

Comment: @NinoFiliu thanks, that's what SO is for. I'll file it now then, just want to make sure I'm not being stupid. Bug target tsc or rxjs?

Comment: Comment the link to the issue when you're done, it is of interest to me and likely will to other visiting the question

Comment: @NinoFiliu https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4448

Comment: This probably doesn't help much but it works on node 8.12.0 for me. Same code and settings with `rxjs`, `ts-node`, `typescript` and `@types/node` dependencies. Only tweak I made though was to change the module to `commonjs` in the tsconfig file to get it to compile (otherwise I'd get a `Unexpected token import` error).

Comment: @JeffMercado see the update below

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Problem

TypeScript has two modes.

1. A project-builder mode (when `tsc` is invoked with no arguments)
2. A compile-mode (when `tsc` is invoked with any arguments) **which does not read from the configuration file `tsconfig.json`**

If that sounds confusing, it's even more confusing when you account for

1. the flag for the compiler-mode to accept a configuration file is called `--project`
2. inside the project-builder's configuration file there the pragma is called "compilerOptions"
3. the compiler-mode and the project-builder mode accept the same configuration file

Anyway, the problem here was that TypeScript was simply ignoring the configuration file in the current working directory that I was running it in.

If you want to see this changed vote here,

- https://twitter.com/TheEvanCarroll/status/1080899909522477061

This is further reported here,

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29241

Comment: I hit this problem with Karma. As described above the tsconfig.json file was ignored. I fixed it by changing the setting the karma property karmaTypescriptConfig. compilerOptions.target to "ES6" See https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-typescript#advanced-configuration

Answer (score 21):

Just install @types/node from npm. This should solve the problem.

```
npm install @types/node
```

Comment: As the commenters replying to the question stated, this is a problem with RxJs, and is not simply fixed by installing `@types/node`.

Comment: Fixed issue for me - using Astro v4.2.3 with React, the issue was in .tsx file

Answer (score 6):

In my case I simply added a `tsconfig.json` file with the following contents where the significant part relating to the above error is `"target": "es2015"`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es2015"
    },
    "include": [
        "file.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139122/error-ts1219-experimental-support-for-decorators-is-a-feature-that-is-subject-t) that worked for me:

> Check if the tsconfig.json file has build in Properties set to "Content" rather than "None", if not right click on the tsconfig file and set the build action to Content. After this reload the project, the error should go away

Comment: thanks, I did this but it came with different errors and switch back again to "None" and it compile correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this while compiling.

```
tsc async_await.ts --lib es2015
```

Comment: It's not clear how this answers the question. Can you elaborate?